# Mapstruct Mapping nested classes issue

Tags: java, mapstruct

i have an issue with my mapping definition. I hope you can give me a hint how to fix it.
My initial situation is, that I have classes with nested classes. Most of the attributes of the Input-nested class could be directly mapped to the target-nested class. But one attribute of the input-nested class must be mapped to the taget class directly.

This is my code:

```
public class Input {

    public String aa;
    public NestedClass nestedMember;
    
    public static class NestedClass {
        public String ab;
        public String ac;
        public String ad;
        public String ae;
    }
}

public class Target {

    public NestedClass nestedMember;
    
    public static class NestedClass {
        public String ba;
        public String bb;
        public String bc;
        public String bd;
    }
}

    @Mapping(target = "nestedMember.ba", source = "aa")
    @Mapping(target = "nestedMember", source = "nestedMember")
    Target map(Input input);
    
    @Mapping(target = "bb", source = "ab")
    @Mapping(target = "bc", source = "ac")
    @Mapping(target = "bd", source = "ad")
    @Mapping(target = "ba", ignore = true)
    NestedClass mappingNested(test.Input.NestedClass nestedClass);
```

My assumption was, that mapstruct will use the mappingNested method for mapping the nested class and then a direct attribute mapping for aa to nestedMember.ba.

But the generated class looks like this:

```
public class MyMapperImpl implements MyMapper {

    @Override
    public Target map(Input input) {
        if ( input == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Target target = new Target();

        if ( input.nestedMember != null ) {
            if ( target.nestedMember == null ) {
                target.nestedMember = new NestedClass();
            }
            nestedClassToNestedClass( input.nestedMember, target.nestedMember );
        }
        if ( target.nestedMember == null ) {
            target.nestedMember = new NestedClass();
        }
        inputToNestedClass( input, target.nestedMember );

        return target;
    }

    @Override
    public NestedClass mappingNested(test.Input.NestedClass nestedClass) {
        if ( nestedClass == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        NestedClass nestedClass1 = new NestedClass();

        nestedClass1.bb = nestedClass.ab;
        nestedClass1.bc = nestedClass.ac;
        nestedClass1.bd = nestedClass.ad;

        return nestedClass1;
    }

    protected void nestedClassToNestedClass(test.Input.NestedClass nestedClass, NestedClass mappingTarget) {
        if ( nestedClass == null ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    protected void inputToNestedClass(Input input, NestedClass mappingTarget) {
        if ( input == null ) {
            return;
        }

        mappingTarget.ba = input.aa;
    }
}
```

So mapstruct gernerates the mappingNested method correctly, but doesn't use it to map the nestedClasses. Mapstuct generates a method (nestedClassToNestedClass) without any mappings. If I remove the explicit aa mapping, everithing works fine. But then I have the problem how I should mapp the aa mapping? I don't what to map every attribute of the nestedClass in the map-method.
Does anybody has an Idea?
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution:

```
@Mapping(target = "nestedMember", source = ".")
    Target map(Input input);
    
    @Mapping(target = "bb", source = "nestedClass.ab")
    @Mapping(target = "bc", source = "nestedClass.ac")
    @Mapping(target = "bd", source = "nestedClass.ad")
    @Mapping(target = "ba", ignore = true)
    NestedClass mappingNested(test.Input.NestedClass nestedClass);
    
    
    default NestedClass mappingNested(Input input) {
        NestedClass nestedClass = mappingNested(input.nestedMember);
        nestedClass.ba = input.aa;
        return nestedClass;
    }
```